# Dropping Demonstrative Pronouns

Tags: english-comparison, pronouns

When using an informal tone, is it common to drop Demonstrative Pronouns? For instance in English your grand father might stand at his door looking out at people outside making noise and say "darn kids!" instead of "Those darn kids!".

Does the same apply for Italian? Would my Italian grand-father say something like "quei fastidiosi ragazzi!" or can you simply drop the "quei" and say "fastidiosi ragazzi!"?

Comment: I cannot think of single phrase without swearing involved at the moment... :D

Comment: Probabilmente tuo nonno direbbe 'Maledetti ragazzi!!' come esclamazione ma non 'Quei maledetti ragazzi', same as in English!

Comment: @Josh61 That's not really true because it sounds pretty good and clean. "Ah, quei maledetti ragazzi" is a common form, especially if you're targeting a fixed, and maybe recurring, set of guys.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can either use the demonstrative or not, but we don’t usually use “quello”: we use ”questo”, and above all “’sto”, the aphaeretic form of “questo” common in everyday, informal speech and in several dialects.

If you’re angry, you’re more likely to say “’Sti maledetti ragazzini!” rather than “Questi maledetti ragazzini!” (which sounds more calm, polite). You can certainly say just “Maledetti ragazzini!”. “’Sto” here is more like an intensifier than a plain demonstrative.

Comment: The English equivalent of "Sti maledetti ragazzini"  would probably be  "The dam kids!"